# Interactive Image With Multiple Mouse Overs

Tags: html, css, css-position, mouseover

In order to teach the different components of a website, I have a giant image (made in photoshop) with a bunch of boxes labeled header, sidebar, content, footer etc all in one image. Using absolutely positioned divs with images inside, I have made it so that when moused over certain parts of the image, like for example the logo, a box appears with information about that specific part of the website and this box appears on top of the logo.

The problem is that this doesn't seem to work in internet explorer (the images never appear) and the images are out of place on a Mac in Safari. The feature I am describing can be seen [here](http://tsawebmaster1.hhstsa.com/web_design.html#extensive_web_look)
and some samples from my code are below. Is there a better way I can accomplish this task, or solve the problem of the images not appearing in internet explorer and being positioned differently on Macs in Safari?

HTML

```
<div class="look" id="look1"><img src="images/extensive_look/logo_info.jpg" width="326"   height="109" alt="Logo Information"></div>
<div class="look" id="look2"><img src="images/extensive_look/header_info.jpg" width="236" height="74" alt="Header Information"></div>
<img src="images/extensive_look/website_layout.jpg" width="1200" height="890"  alt="Website Layout">
```

CSS

```
.look:hover img{
visibility:visible; 
}
.look {
position: absolute;
left: 320px;
top: 328px;
}

#look1 {
top:211px;
left:53px;  
}

#look2 {
top: 205px;
left: 487px;
}

#look3 {
top: 282px;
left: 403px;
```

Comment: To help with that I'd need to literally see the site.

Comment: The site is http://tsawebmaster1.hhstsa.com/web_design.html#extensive_web_look.

Comment: Ah, the part where images wont appear is probably due to z-index in IE. Instead of using an img, try putting the image as a background-image of a div and having the other items in that div, alone with the image.

Comment: So are you saying I should put the big layout image in a div along with the other smaller images. I'm guessing I should just add a high z-index to all the #look(1,2,3,etc) divs then to solve that problem. What about the fact that the divs are appearing in different locations depending upon the browser?

Comment: Well I don't have a mac so I cannot reproduce that one. Both my browsers on this PC have only a tiny difference. What is strange though is that the content in the middle only appears when i scroll down a ton but the mouseovers appear even when nothing is there. That surely cannot be intended, right?

Also, by doing the background image thing, it might solve that because the slight difference in position is caused by the font-size of the text above that image. So perhaps it is the same with the safari thing.

Comment: The middle content was actually intentional to initially keep the layout cleaner until the user is within view. I'll try that out.

Comment: You can put it just above, it doesn't really change a thing.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this to complement the comment:

```
<div>
<h1 align="center">Extensive Look at a Website</h1><p style="width:800px;margin:0 auto;">As you can see in step 1 of the 7 steps, web design begins with an understanding of a website. Below is a model website featuring the different components of a website. As you scroll, make sure to mouse over the different components to get information on that component. It is important to note that while these are common parts of most websites, not every website will have every component.</p>
  <p style="width:800px;margin:0 auto;">&nbsp;</p>
</div>
<div class="content" style="position:relative;width:1200px;height:890px;background-image:url('images/extensive_look/website_layout.jpg');">
<div class="look" id="look1"><img src="images/extensive_look/logo_info.jpg" alt="Logo Information" height="109" width="326"></div> 

rest of look things here. 
</div>
```

Comment: So I tried it, and it still seems to be a little off between browsers. Internet explorer is being extremely difficult because it is still completely invisible. I also noticed that it seems every one of my elements with z:index is like that.

Comment: Which version of IE? Anything below 10 is problematic. I think its coded like "if runs on another browser then break it else break it just in case";

Comment: However, for your page, it will work if you put the text outside and use the image as a background image.

Comment: I think it's working now. There's some slight differences in positioning but nothing major. Thank you so much.

Comment: Congrats. Perhaps having a [CSS reset script first](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/reset.css) then putting the look container to position:relative, then repositioning the looks would solve the slight position issues.